# How to subscript string in QComboBox's addItem

Tags: pyqt, qcombobox

I am trying to enter a chemical formula using addItem to a QComboBox, but I do not know how to subscript the numbers. I would really appreciate any help I can receive.

I have tried:
1. Using dollar signs ($) before and after the number "$\3$"
2. Using curly brackets and dollar signs "$_{3}$"
3. Using Unicode formatting "\u2083". This one works but it only shows the sub scripted number when you see the options of the drop down menu. After you select the option, it'll display a vertical bar in place of the number (see pics)

[image]

```
self.amp_sub1_Box = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
self.amp_sub1_Box.addItem("H")
self.amp_sub1_Box.addItem("CH\u2083")
self.amp_sub1_Box.addItem("CH\u2082CH\u2083")
```

Comment: Looks like a font-related issue. A different font is being used in the drop-down (and there is no anti-aliasing). I wonder if the font used for the selected item does not support characters outside the Latin1/Windows-1252 range? Try setting a font on the checkbox that has proper unicode support (e.g. DejaVu Sans).

Comment: Thank you! This worked. After changing the font type to Verdana, I actually became able to see the subscripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ekhumoro suggested in the comments, changing the font style solved this problem. Just use: `QComboBox.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Verdana'))`

Answer (score 0):

unicode formatting should work. In this example subscripted numbers are correctly shown in drop down list as well as in selected items:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets

 class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self): 
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self) 
        self.setGeometry(200,100,600,700)
        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.setGeometry(50,100,300,25)
        items = ('CH3-CH3','CH\u2083-CH\u2083','H2O','H\u20820','H2SO4','H\u2082SO\u2084')
        for i in range(0,len(items)):
            self.combo.addItem(items[i])

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
widget = MyWidget()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I edited my original post and added an image. I tried it again but still not working.

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1

Comment: curious, i tried it on ubuntu 14.04 and windows 7, both successful