# Using superscript in QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox

I used a similar approach in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522612/how-to-subscript-string-in-qcomboboxs-additem) to add superscripts to some items in my combobox. But using the unicode and setting the font doesn't work.

Here is the code I used:

```
# Define squared units
units = ['m\u00B2', 'km\u00B2']
self.dockwidget.comboBox.clear()
self.dockwidget.comboBox.addItems(oppMap_units)
self.dockwidget.comboBox.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Verdana'))
```

[image: Example]

---

My Qt version is 4.8.5

Comment: if python2: `units = [u'm\u00B2', u'km\u00B2']`.

Comment: @ekhumoro - Indeed, many thanks! Forgot to mention I was using Python2, could you please post your comment as an **answer**? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python 2, you must remember to use unicode:

```
units = [u'm\u00B2', u'km\u00B2']
```

Otherwise, the strings will be decoded as ascii.